# UITableView not updating UIButton after cell reuse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView with a custom cell, called `resultsCell`. It contains 4 UILabels and 6 UIButtons, and looks like this (I labeled what type each box is):
[image: Cell]

There are about 10 of these cells in the UITableView, so of course the cells are reused. Whenever I scroll up and down multiple times, each UILabel in the cell is updated to each cell perfectly, however, UIButtons do not always update correctly, and a different value is shown. Each button is linked to an IBAction that redirects the user to a different view with a segue. How can I fix the UIButtons not updating? Or is there a better way to do this without buttons?

CODE:

UITableViewCell class:

```
class ResultsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var red1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var red2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var red3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var redScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var blue1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var blue2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var blue3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var blueScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var teamsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    override func prepareForReuse() { //I tried doing this with no luck.
        super.prepareForReuse()
        red1?.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        red2?.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        red3?.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        blue1?.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        blue2?.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        blue3?.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    }

}
```

UITableView Dequeue Reusable Cell code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultsCell") as! ResultsTableViewCell
    let thisMatch = resultsDict[indexPath.row] as! [String:String]
    cell.red1?.setTitle(thisMatch["red2"], for: .normal)
    cell.red2?.setTitle(thisMatch["red2"], for: .normal)
    cell.red3?.setTitle(thisMatch["red3"], for: .normal)
    cell.blue1?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue1"], for: .normal)
    cell.blue2?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue2"], for: .normal)
    cell.blue3?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue3"], for: .normal)
    cell.redScore?.text = thisMatch["redScore"]
    cell.blueScore?.text = thisMatch["blueScore"]
    if (playerID == thisMatch["red1"]) {
        cell.red1?.underline()
    } else if (playerID == thisMatch["red2"]) {
        cell.red2?.underline()
    } else if (playerID == thisMatch["red3"]) {
        cell.red3?.underline()
    } else if (playerID == thisMatch["blue1"]) {
        cell.blue1?.underline()
    } else if (playerID == thisMatch["blue2"]) {
        cell.blue2?.underline()
    } else if (playerID == thisMatch["blue3"]) {
        cell.blue3?.underline()
    }

    return cell    
}
```

thisMatch

```
{
        "red1": "1234",
        "red2": "4567",
        "red3": "8901",
        "blue1": "2345",
        "blue2": "6789",
        "blue3": "0123",
        "redScore": "456",
        "blueScore": "789",
}
```

What the buttons should display:

[image: cell]

underline extension:

```
extension UIButton {
func underline() {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.titleLabel?.text!)!)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle,
                                  value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (self.titleLabel?.text!.count)!))
    self.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
}

}
```

Comment: @matt I'm sorry, I copied my code wrong. I actually set 6 buttons, and I updated my code above. I have also tested instead of buttons to have labels, and the information from `resultsDict[indexPath.row]` updates correctly, so it's not the information.

Comment: Try logging `thisMatch` against the `indexPath.row` and see if it shows anything different from what you are expecting. There is a good chance that `thisMatch` has wrong value if you using above code.

Comment: @matt Ok, I'll log `thisMatch` and `indexPath.row` to see if it is wrong.  I'll also share what `thisMatch` is and a screenshot of what the buttons display

Comment: @adev I tried logging it in the console, and I'm getting the results I'm expecting, but the buttons have incorrect values

Comment: @matt I traced back each outlet, and they are set up correctly. I included what `thisMatch` contains in the question. The buttons display `red1`, `red2`, `red3`, `blue1`, `blue2`, `blue3`. I also logged what it's supposed to display and `indexPath.row`, and it logs the results I'm expecting, but the buttons display completely different numbers

Comment: @matt I posted a screenshot of what the cell buttons display at the bottom of my question. It displays the values of `red1`, `red2`, `red3`, `blue1`, `blue2`, `blue3` in `thisMatch`

Comment: The screen shot you posted matches the value of `thisMatch` in the log (except for  the first 0123 which looks like a misprint). So there's no problem so far.

Comment: @matt I think I may have found the problem. While getting actual screenshots of before and after scrolling, I couldn't seem to reproduce the error anymore. For the screenshots, I commented code that underlines my player number in the cell, and I believe that was causing the buttons not to update. I found the code to underline text in buttons online, and I will put it in the question. It uses `NSMutableAttributedString`. Do you know why this might cause this problem? and is there something I can do in the `override func prepareForReuse()` function to undo this? (I also added the underline code)

Answer (score 0):

Each Button is reusing, so we should assign case of without underlining also. try with this code.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultsCell") as! ResultsTableViewCell
    let thisMatch = resultsDict[indexPath.row] as! [String:String]

    cell.redScore?.text = thisMatch["redScore"]
    cell.blueScore?.text = thisMatch["blueScore"]


    if (playerID == thisMatch["red1"]) {
        cell.red1?.setTitle(thisMatch["red1"], for: .normal)
        cell.red1?.underline()
    } else {
       cell.red1?.setTitle(thisMatch["red1"], for: .normal)
    }


    if (playerID == thisMatch["red2"]) {
        cell.red2?.setTitle(thisMatch["red2"], for: .normal)
        cell.red2?.underline()
    }else {
        cell.red2?.setTitle(thisMatch["red2"], for: .normal)
    }

    if (playerID == thisMatch["red3"]) {
        cell.red3?.setTitle(thisMatch["red3"], for: .normal)
        cell.red3?.underline()
    } else {
        cell.red3?.setTitle(thisMatch["red3"], for: .normal)
    }

    if (playerID == thisMatch["blue1"]) {
        cell.blue1?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue1"], for: .normal)
        cell.blue1?.underline()
    } else {
        cell.blue1?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue1"], for: .normal)
    }

    if (playerID == thisMatch["blue2"]) {
        cell.blue2?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue2"], for: .normal)
        cell.blue2?.underline()
    }else {
        cell.blue2?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue2"], for: .normal)
    }

     if (playerID == thisMatch["blue3"]) {
        cell.blue3?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue3"], for: .normal)
        cell.blue3?.underline()
     } else {
        cell.blue3?.setTitle(thisMatch["blue3"], for: .normal)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately when cells reuse it does not remove the underline and the numbers keep changing from the buttons

Comment: There was a problem in this loop , if (playerID == thisMatch["red1"]) {, i edited answer. try with this and try to remove the prepare for reuse code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it as soon as possible and let you know if it works. :)